# Fixed div to disappear under unfixed div when scrolling

Tags: jquery, css

**[JSFIDDLE here](http://jsfiddle.net/28gWb/1/)**

Fiddle works as it should be but now I want to change the way it works. Currently only `fixed_header_top` is permanently fixed and I want `fixed_header_middle` to be fixed permanently as well but should gradually **disappear under** `fixed_header_bottom` and `body_block` when scrolling down.

Like this one: http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_43176/index.html

What do I need to change for this action?

I gave `position: fixed;` to `#fixed_header_middle` and `margin-top: 50px; z-index: 100;` to `#fixed_header_bottom, #fixed_placeholder` but didn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

**Modified CSS:**

```
#top
{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #1133DD;
}
#fixed_header_top
{
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #DD33DD;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 100;
}
#fixed_header_middle
{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #DDDD00;
    top: 50px;
}
```

**Modified HTML:**

```
<div id="top">
    <div id="fixed_header_top">fixed_header_top</div>
    <div id="fixed_header_middle">fixed_header_middle</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check i have done on fiddle
What you have done is corect just you have to add

```
#fixed_header_bottom, #fixed_placeholder {

   margin-top: 150px;
   position: absolute;

}
```

[Check on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rahulsharma2r/28gWb/2/)

Comment: You want header and middle fixed and while others are scrolling?

Comment: No. `top` is always fixed and visible. `middle` fixed under `top` at the beginning but starts disappearing under `bottom` and `body` when scrolled down. So at the end of the page only `top` and `bottom` becomes fixed and visible.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your CSS and its working fine now

**[See Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/28gWb/3/)**

Modified CSS

```
#fixed_header_middle {
    /*other stuff*/
    position: fixed;
    z-index:-1;
}

#fixed_header_bottom {
    margin-top: 150px;
}

.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    margin-top: 0!important; /*Important because Id has more weight*/
}

#body_block {
    background:#FFF;
}
```